# Where Annotation in hibernate with date as clause

Tags: java, hibernate

I was wondering if there was a way to use the `@Where(clause="")` to bind a Set of things where `is_active=1 AND expires_date <= new Date()` in a `@OneToMany` relationship.

Something like this

```
@Where(clause="is_active=1 AND expires_date <=" + new Date())
```

Or can you only do it with constants?

This code will not work just looking for a work around or if there is a way to do this.
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Where.clause` can only be a constant and what are trying to do is impossible.
You can retrieve data using a business method via query/named-query or, maybe, using a [filter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html) because filters can be manually activated and has parameters.
If you need to get unexpired data for a report a business method is the right way; if you want to see only unexpired data during work session in a trasparent way a filter can be the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I was hoping there would be a way to do this, but I guess I'll have to go with using a filter.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using criteria in hibernate. Before implementing the above code make sure that you have an active session open.

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(yourclassname.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("is_active", 1));
criteria.add(Restrictions.le("expires_date", rightNow));
```

Comment: Will look into this further it seems like this method would be to not bind the entities together. and just make a DAO call to get the results I want, is that what you're saying?

Comment: no, lets say you have a class A and class A has 2 fields called is_active and expires_date then the above criteria[in hibernate we query on classes not on tables like in basic sql] will query the result based on those condition. let me know if you want more clarifications on this

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but you could do this using sql functions like current_date in postgresql :

```
@Where(clause="is_active=1 AND expires_date <= current_date")
```